# GWT Model View Presenter , Reusing Presenters ? Or Presenter - Presenter Communication

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt, mvp, presenter

A rookie here.

I just started with Ray Ryan's Google IO talk and following some articles on Google Developers site. I have not used any of the GWT add-ons like GWTP or MVP4G or GIN or any other stuff. Just followed the contacts example on the GWT site and tried to model my case.

I have a **DockLayout** panel which has a header, a navigation tree on the left and a central main panel. All of this i have in a single **DefaultView** which implements **DefaultPresenter** .

Now i have a **DialogBox** which  pops up when the user does something in the tree and this is modelled in **DialogView** and **DialogPresenter** respectively.

Now when i hide the **DialogBox** , i am ending up calling a new instance of **DefaultPresenter** from the **AppController** which by virtue creates a **new DefaultView** and all of my tree selections and other changes in the main central panel are gone.

1. Is it possible to re use instances of presenters without creating a new one on history change  ? (for eg, **DefaultPresenter** in my case)
2. Is there a way in MVP pattern to pass controls between presenters with values persisting ?
3. How to load a existing instance of a presenter inside app controller on an event fire ?

Or have i got the whole MVP architecture thing wrong ? I am now planning to have different presenters and views for each of my components say **HeaderPresenter / HeaderView, TreePresenter / TreeView , MainContentPresenter/MainContentView** ?So that i will only create new instances of presenters which i need (like **MainContentPresenter** ) and keep the existing ones as it is (like **TreePresenter and HeaderPresenter**)  Does this solve my problem ? How would i stitch all of this different views in the browser window ? **I am not using UiBInder** , just sticking to basics .

Help me out all you experts, i am in a deadlock !

Answer (score 2):

When I read your question it felt like the answer should be an article, something along the lines of *Stateful Presenter Architecture for GWT Apps*. This is StackOverflow, however, which is all about conciseness, so let's see:

### Answers

> `1.` Is it possible to re use instances of presenters without creating a new one on history change?

Definitely. Nothing prevents you from switching between a bunch of singleton presenters injected with your views (the switching will happen in your implementation of [ActivityMapper](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/ActivityMapper.html)). **Note** the assumption from hereafter that your presenters are [Activities](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/Activity.html).

> `2.` Is there a way in MVP pattern to pass controls between presenters with values persisting ?

Since your presenters are now singletons they'll retain the state of their member variables. For message exchange between presenters, events and [EventBus](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/shared/EventBus.html) are your friends.

> `3.` How to load a existing instance of a presenter inside app controller on an event fire ?

Your `ActivityMapper` instance, once registered with your [ActivityManager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/activity/shared/ActivityManager.html), should suffice. The `ActivityManager` will rely on your implementation of `public Activity getActivity(Place place)` of the `ActivityMapper` interface to return one of your singleton presenters.

### Resources

[David Chandler's Google I/O 2011 GWT session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0F5zc1UAt2Y) touches on exactly this type of master/details architecture. I highly recommend it in general and for this question specifically the part following the 18th minute, when David begins a thorough overview of Activities and Places.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ! Will try out the activities thing and get back !

Comment: @Napster did you manage to make reusable presenters work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(, we settled for a quick fix which works for our problem but we are still creating presenters everytime (not optimal though )